# Order of Complex Exponential

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose n is divisible by the number $p^k$ where p is prime. How do I show that the order of $e^{i2\pi m /n}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible by $(p - 1)p^{k - 1}$ when m and n are co prime? If $x$ is the order that would mean $\frac{mx}{n} \in \mathbb{N}$. Since m and n are coprime, this means n divides x, which would mean $p^k$ divides the order. But that does not prove my claim. These were my first thoughts. Now I think order means degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ as an algebraic number. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem that the question should say "degree" instead of order. When $m,n$ are coprime, the element you wrote down is a primitive $n$th root of unity (because, as you observed when working with multiplicative order, it has order at least $n$, and hence exactly $n$).

The degree of a primitive $n$th root of unity over $\mathbb Q$ is $\phi(n)$. If we write $n = p^r d$ with $p$ not dividing $d$, then
$$\phi(n) = \phi(p^r) \phi(d) = (p-1)p^{r-1} \phi(d)$$
by assumption, $p^k | n$ so $r \geq k$ and hence $p^{k-1}|p^{r-1}$ so $(p-1)p^k$ divides the right hand side, as desired.

Comment: Toucan Why is the degree of the $n$th root of unity equal to the Euler Toitent function?

Comment: Toucan, Since I assumed m and n are co-prime, why can I write $n = p^rm$? Doesn't that mean m divides n, which would imply gcd(m,n) = m?

Comment: Sorry that was bad notation, I forgot you already used $m$ for something else. My $m$ was entirely unrelated to your $m$. I just changed that. As far as the degree of the $n$th root of unity, this is a general fact that I assume would be proven prior to asking this question.

Comment: By bad. I forgot that that cyclotomic polynomials were defined as $\prod_{k = 1,k|n}^{n - 1}(x - \alpha^k)$, where $\alpha$ is primitive n th root of unity. Thought it was for all k between 1 and n - 1. Brain fart.